# Locally Compact Hausdorff Topologial Group but not Sequential?

Tags: general-topology, locally-compact-groups

Does there exist a locally compact Hausdorff topological group that is not sequential?

Edit: What is a sequential space? Let $X$ be a topological space. 
A subset $F$ of $X$ is sequentially closed if, whenever $(x_n)$ is a sequence in $F$ converging to $x$, then $x$ must also be in $F$. Every closed set in $X$ is sequentially closed. If every sequentially closed set in $X$ is closed, then $X$ is called a sequential space. Roughly, sequentially spaces are those whose topology is determined by the convergent sequences in the space. All metric spaces and all first-countable spaces are sequential.

Comment: What does “sequential” mean?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: A topological space is sequential if every subset which is closed under taking limits of sequences is closed.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure.  For instance, if $I$ is an uncountable set, the product $\{0,1\}^I$ is not sequential, but is a compact Hausdorff topological group by taking addition mod $2$ on each coordinate.  (To see it is not sequential, note that the set of elements which are $0$ on all but countably many coordinates is sequentially closed but not closed.)

Comment: This was the first example that came to mind for me as well.